# ¿Como puedo implementar un header CSP (Content Security Policy) en Angular 9?

Tags: angular, typescript, spring-boot, seguridad, headers

estoy desarrollando una aplicacion web con Angular 9 para el frontend y Spring Boot para el backend, estoy por terminarla aplicacion como tal, sin embargo, estoy revisando temas de seguridad para lo cual tengo que implementar el uso de un header CSP (Content Security Policy) para el tema del clickjacking pero no he podido entender como realizar esto de manera efectiva a pesar de revisar algunos foros donde indican el uso de la etiqueta meta como se muestra a continuacion:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="frame-src 'self'" />
```

Sin embargo, el uso de esta etiqueta no me funciona en lo mas minimo, por lo que no se que mas hacer. Alguien podria sugerirme como agregar dicho header?

Comment: Ese header debe enviarlo el servidor en la respuesta al cliente.

Comment: @Lobos y como hago eso en AppEngine o el servidor que use angular?